# Add HomeMade Analytics Service on some ASP.net pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I made a webservice that logs some information.
This webservice must be used when a user visits some webpages.

I don't think that a log called by a javascript (ajax) called from html is the solution.

Or calling a Manager in the controller to log?

Or should I use Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax? I could search for a webpage name in the config.file to know if the page has to be logged or not? If yes, How?

Other solutions?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should define an `Interface` and then derive every classes which you want to do logging  from that interface.

Comment: aha great idea @user26, but there are multiple controllers in the same class and I don't want to log all controller of the class. Second question : did you think I can access to the cache in this logging class?

Comment: for your first part: you can manage that, for your second question, it depends on where you have cached the data, but you can pass the wanted cache!

Comment: Because Global.asax can't provide the caller page URL, so I was unable to log the URL, I finally made a controller that just log and this controller is called with jquery (ajax) on each page I want to log. The partial view return nothing.